# How to fill shape white

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

#### Description

Hi, I am trying to make objects to take damage and I want to add a cool effect.

#### Problem

When I type this command: `player.img.fill((255, 255, 255))`

I get this:

[image]

and I want to get this:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to get the mask from the image with `pygame.mask.from_surface`:

```py
player_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(player.img)
```

Then you can use `to_surface` to create an image from the mask. Make the background of the image transparent with `set_colorkey()`:

```py
mask_image = player_mask.to_surface(setcolor = (255, 255, 255))
mask_image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 100))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player_image = pygame.image.load('Bird.png')
player_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(player_image)
mask_image = player_mask.to_surface(setcolor = (255, 255, 255))
mask_image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window.fill((0, 32, 64))
    window.blit(player_image, player_image.get_rect(center = (50, 50)))
    window.blit(mask_image, mask_image.get_rect(center = (150, 50)))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```